# Should I consider not reporting a grade on my transcript?

Tags: undergraduate, transcript-of-records

I'm an undergrad student. The grading scale in my university is designed like 4.0, 3.5, 3.0... Due to the pandemic, our school gives us a chance to select the S/NS grading option, I kept a very good overall cumulative GPA, but this semester there's a class I got 3.0 (all the other classes in that subject are 4.0 on my transcript), I want to replace that 3.0 grade with an 'S' (means satisfactory) on my transcript. However, some of my friends don't think it's a good idea since it will make graduate admission officers guess my grade for that class. My question is if I want to apply for the doctorate programs, how important is the transcript? Is it a good idea for me to replace the grade to avoid dropping the cumulative grade? If I replace the grade then I'll be eligible to graduate with high honors. Any comments/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/35240/potential-impact-of-pass-fail-vs-letter-grade-in-elective-courses